# Best practice for arranging images in waterfall pattern

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm developing an iOS app, in swift, and I'm about to make a view that's displaying many images in a specific pattern in a scroll view. I'm not sure about the correct name for this type of pattern, but I've heard it mentioned as waterfall pattern.

[image]

So an image has a fixed width, and is then resized with a variable height to fit the original aspect ratio. The images will be fetched form a webserver, and there could potentionally be a lot.

**My question is:**

How would you recommend that I implemented this? Just as a lot of manually sized images in a scroll view, or should I use a collection view? Is the collection view capable of having many different sized cells, and how will I know in what column to put a newly added image?

I hope this isn't a too broad question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Check out CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout to see how it can be done.

https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Comment: AWESOME.! This was just what I was looking for. Thank you :)